# Spring boot application that would read configuration from Key vault and connect to SQL?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

I am not a Java/Spring Boot developer however I want to build a simple Spring boot application which would read configuration from Key vault and connect to SQL.

I have two separate solutions for each one of those

Key vault solution is to read the secrets from the Azure Key vault

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class KeyvaultApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(KeyvaultApplication.class, args);
   }

  @GetMapping("get")
  public String get() {
    return connectionString;
  }

  @Value("${connectionString}")
  private String connectionString;

  public void run(String... varl) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(String.format("\nConnection String stored in Azure Key Vault:\n%s\n",connectionString));
  }  

}
```

**application.properties**

```
azure.keyvault.client-id=xxxx
azure.keyvault.client-key=xxxx
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=xxxxx
azure.keyvault.uri=https://xxxxx-keyvault85.vault.azure.net/
```

======================================================================

and SQL solution to insert the data into the Azure SQL Database

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx-sql.database.windows.net:1433;database=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=spring@databasename
spring.datasource.password=Password

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
```

**TodoController.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TodoController {

    private final TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public TodoController(TodoRepository todoRepository) {
        this.todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Todo createTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Iterable<Todo> getTodos() {
        return todoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**TodoRepository.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {
}
```

**Todo.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Todo {

    public Todo() {
    }

    public Todo(String description, String details, boolean done) {
        this.description = description;
        this.details = details;
        this.done = done;
    }

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    private String details;

    private boolean done;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }
}
```

Both the solution works independently however I want to combine the solutions so that I can read the SQL configuration from the  Azure Key vault and connect with Azure SQL database. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you could ref this document: [Tutorial: Reading a secret from Azure Key Vault in a Spring Boot application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault):

Spring Boot applications externalize sensitive information such as    usernames and passwords. Externalizing sensitive information enables    better maintainability, testability, and security. Storing secrets    outside of the code is better than hard coding the information, or inlining it at build time.

This tutorial describes how to create a Spring Boot app that reads a    value from Azure Key Vault, then deploy the app to Azure App Service    and Azure Spring Cloud.

Summaries of [Add Key Vault integration to the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#add-key-vault-integration-to-the-app):

Follow these steps to add the necessary configuration to **application.properties** file.

1. Open src/main/resources/application.properties in an editor and make
   it have the following contents, adjusting the values for your Azure
   subscription.

   ```
   azure.keyvault.client-id=685on005-ns8q-4o04-8s16-n7os38o2ro5n
   azure.keyvault.client-key=4bt.lCKJKlbYLn_3XF~wWtUwyHU0jKggu2
   azure.keyvault.enabled=true
   azure.keyvault.tenant-id=72s988os-86s1-41ns-91no-2q7pq011qo47
   azure.keyvault.uri=https://contosokv.vault.azure.net/
   ```

   The complete list of properties available is documented in the
   [property reference](https://aka.ms/azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets).
2. Save the file and close it.

Make one simple changes to the KeyvaultApplication.java file (or whatever the class name is in your case).

1. Open src/main/java/com/contoso/keyvault/KeyvaultApplication.java in
   a text editor.
2. Add this import.

   ```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   ```
3. Add an annotation to the connectionString instance variable.

   ```
   @Value("${connectionString}")
   private String connectionString;
   ```

   The Key Vault integration provides a Spring `PropertySource` that is populated from the
   values of the Key Vault. Some more implementation details are available in the
   [reference documentation](https://aka.ms/azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets).
4. In the top level keyvault directory, where the pom.xml file is
   located, enter `mvn clean package spring-boot:run`.
5. The message initialization completed in the command output means the
   server is ready. In a separate shell window, enter this command.

   ```
   Bash
   $ curl http://localhost:8080/get
   ```

   The output will show
   `jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;database=DATABASE` instead of
   `defaultValue`.
6. Kill the process that is running from `mvn spring-boot:run`. You can
   type Ctrl-C or you can use the `jps` command to get the pid of the
   `Launcher` process and kill it.

Hope it can help you figure it out.

Comment: I could read the secret from azure key vault however I want to set the below application properties to connect with Azure Sql database logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx-sql.database.windows.net:1433;database=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=spring@databasename
spring.datasource.password=Password

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without exposing azure.keyvault.client-key in the application.properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your properties with '-' instead of '.'

For example:
spring.datasource.username=spring@databasename

In azure cli:

```
az keyvault secret set --name "spring-datasource-username" --vault-name "your-key-vault" --value "spring@databasename"
```

OR in azure portal:

your key vault should be this

```
name:
spring-datasource-username

value:
spring@databasename
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my day! Spring recognizes `spring.data.password` as the same as same as `spring-data-password`.

Answer (score 1):

From what i tried with this verison

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

only 3 parameters are needed.

YAML file

```
azure:
  keyvault:
    client-id: xxxxxxx
    client-key: xxxxxxyyyyy
    enabled: true
    uri: https://xxx.vault.azure.net/
```

Then Config class

```
@Configuration
public class AzureConfig {

  @Value("${azure.keyvault.client-id}")
  private String clientId;

  @Value("${azure.keyvault.client-key}")
  private String clientSecret;

  @Bean
  public KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient() {
    ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new AzureKeyVaultCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    return new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
  }
}
```

Then in service class to autowire `keyVaultClient` to set or get

```
SetSecretRequest secretRequest = new Builder(keyVaultUrl, key, value).build();
keyVaultClient.setSecret(secretRequest);
```

`keyVaultUrl` is key vault host url like `https://xxx.vault.azure.net/`

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to create a `Configuration` class that can initialize a `SecretClient` object for us.

```
@Configuration
public class AzureSecretClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecretClient createSecretClient() {
        return new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl("https://app-kv.vault.azure.net/")
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
    }

}
```

Next step will be to use this configuration object to fetch the secrets from `key-vault` based on `secret-key-name`

A `sql-server configuration` can now use the `AzureSecretClientConfiguration` object to fetch secrets from azure key vault.

I have the below variables defined in `applicaiton.properties`. Please note how each variable refers to the key-name in azure key-vault.

```
# SQL Server Properties
spring.datasource.url.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-uri
spring.datasource.username.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-username
spring.datasource.password.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-password
```

Entries from Azure Key-Vault -
[image]

Now a `Sql Server Config` class can use the previously created `AzureSecretClientConfiguration` SecretClient to fetch and create its own config object. Please refer the `getSecret()` function below -

```
@Configuration
public class SqlServerKeyVaultConfig {
    @Autowired
    AzureSecretClientConfiguration azureSecretClientConfiguration;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerDbUriSecretName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerUsernameSecretName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerPasswordSecretName;

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerDbUrl() {
        System.out.println("Data-source url " + sqlServerDbUriSecretName);
        return getSecret(sqlServerDbUriSecretName);
    }

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerUsername() {
        return getSecret(sqlServerUsernameSecretName);
    }

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerPassword() {
        return getSecret(sqlServerPasswordSecretName);
    }

    private String getSecret(String secretName) {
        return azureSecretClientConfiguration.createSecretClient().getSecret(secretName).getValue();
    }

}
```