# Razor Page Pass Through Azure AD login to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, razor-pages

**Background**: I built a Razor Pages web app that connects to Azure SQL DB and have successfully set up Azure AD single sign on. I have a DB context class which use AD interactive authentication, but when I publish the app to the Web App Service, I have to configure the Azure SQL DB dependency and I am forced to hard-code a username and password.

I have created users and logins in the DB and also utilize RLS as not all users have a need to see all data in certain tables, so I want to retain the security measures already in place.

**Problem**: Because the username and password are hard-coded all users  will be able to see, edit, delete information they shouldn't, so I need to configure pass-through authentication to the DB.

Anyone have examples on how to achieve this?

**Edit**: Just how you can configure Power BI to have end users use their own credentials to access the SQL DB, I need to this with my web app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the username and password, some other way is that you can store the SQL database connection string to the [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal), then use secret key name to connect to the SQL database.

Example ref: [Spring boot application that would read configuration from Key vault and connect to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876781/spring-boot-application-that-would-read-configuration-from-key-vault-and-connect)

Comment: I think this would work if I were using just one username/password to connect to the database. Do you know how I could use the logged in user's info to then pass on to Azure SQL?

Comment: @msearing What's the meaning of  you want to get the username/password from the logged in user and pass to Azure SQL, insert the info to Azure SQL table?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically I need the logged in user to be the user that is connecting to the database. My best example would be how a user logs into Power BI and the database uses those credentials to return data that the user is authorized to view, edit, etc.

Comment: @msearing Did you set the AAD user for the Azure SQL database? If the user is not configured as the SQL database user, you can access it.

Comment: Yes, I have each AAD user as a database user. Right now they only access data through Power BI and their credentials pass-through so they only see data that they are authorized to see.