# How to integrate azure key vault in spring boot with property source?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I am in new in Azure. I created a small application where I have mentioned one secret `JWT-SET-URI` in application.properties file. The secret, I have created in `azure key vaults`.

**Spring boot version: 3.1.5**

**Azure account: Personal Account with free (12 months)**

**application.propeties**

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=${JWT-SET-URI}
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=https://demo-vault.vault.azure.net/
```

Also I have installed `Azure CLI`. Once I ran command `az login` after that if I start the application it is working fine. But when the `Azure CLI` is not present or ran `az logout` command. The application is not starting.

My question is that is there any way that I can run the application without the `Azure CLI` ?

For reference, I have followed this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault

Comment: Check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876781/spring-boot-application-that-would-read-configuration-from-key-vault-and-connect

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the below code without the Azure CLI login method and retrieved the secret from the key vault with the service principal, Client Credentials method.*

**Code :**

***SecretController.java :***

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SecretController {
    @Autowired
    private KeyVaultService keyVaultService;

    @GetMapping("/secret")
    public String getSecret() {
        return keyVaultService.getSecretValue();
    }
}
```

***KeyVaultService.java :***

```java
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class KeyVaultService {
    @Value("${azure.keyvault.vault-url}")
    private String vaultUrl;

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.tenant-id}")
    private String tenantId;

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.secret-name}")
    private String secretName;

    public String getSecretValue() {
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .build();

        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(vaultUrl)
                .credential(clientSecretCredential)
                .buildClient();

        return secretClient.getSecret(secretName).getValue();
    }
}
```

***application.properties :***

```
azure.keyvault.vault-url=https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net
azure.keyvault.client-id=<app_client_id>
azure.keyvault.client-secret=<app_client-secret>
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<tenant-id>
azure.keyvault.secret-name=kamsecret
```

Below is the secret value I have in my key vault.

[image]

I gave access to the app to retrieve the secrets from the key vault as below:

[image]

The code runs successfully as below:

[image]

***I retrieved the secret from the key vault in the browser as below.***

[image]

Comment: Hi @dasari-kamali, Thank you for the response. However, Here you have used `SecretClient`. I want to use `PropertySource` as I need secret value while starting up the application. For example, datasource username, password, url to connect to Database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the exact secret values when running the app locally (because for example you have a local database which has different URL and credentials), then you can simply use a local test double to replace Azure Key Vault as well.

This example project can tell you how the Spring integration should be done as well as how you can replace the real Azure Key Vault with the test double: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example/tree/main#spring-cloud-azure-starter